# How find the $S_{n+2}=AS_{n+1}+BS_{n}$ of the $A,B$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $a_{1}=1,a_{2}=1,$ and such

> $$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$$
>
> and let  $$S_{n}=a_{1}\binom{n}{1}+a_{2}\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+a_{n}\binom{n}{n}$$
>
> if exst constant $A,B$ such
> $$S_{n+2}=AS_{n+1}+BS_{n}$$

Find the $A,B$ value.

Thank you Daniel Fischer hint, I use $S_{1},S_{2},S_{3},S_{4}$ found $A=3,B=-1$

meaning that
$$S_{n+2}=3S_{n+1}-S_{n}$$

But How about prove it?

Comment: Have you tried guessing by computing $S_1, S_2, S_3, \dotsc$ for small indices?

Comment: Oh,Thank you your hint ,I'm try

Comment: I'm try it,Thank you,Now How about prove it

Comment: You can show it directly by induction. That involves some fiddling around with identities between binomial coefficients, and with the recurrence for the $a_n$. Perhaps it's easier to show that $S_n = a_{2n}$ (that too involves some fiddling around). You can also use Binet's formula to show it. What is easiest, or the intended method, that depends on what you have to work with.

Comment: Have you with out induction,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the sequence  $(a_n)$ by setting $a_0=0$. Then the recursion $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ still holds for $n=0$. Recall that ${n\choose k}=0$ if $k\leqslant-1$ or $k\geqslant n+1$, and consider, for every integer $n$,
$$
S_n=\sum_ka_k{n\choose k},\qquad T_n=\sum_ka_k{n\choose k+1},\qquad R_n=\sum_ka_k{n\choose k-1}.
$$
where each sum runs over every integer $k\geqslant 0$. Plugging $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}$ for every $k\geqslant2$ into $R_n$ yields
$$
R_n=1+S_n+T_n.
$$
Plugging ${n+1\choose k}={n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1}$ into $S_{n+1}$ yields
$$
S_{n+1}=\sum_ka_k{n\choose k}+\sum_ka_k{n\choose k-1}=S_n+R_n=2S_n+T_n+1.
$$
Plugging ${n+1\choose k+1}={n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k}$ into $T_{n+1}$ yields
$$
T_{n+1}=\sum_ka_k{n\choose k+1}+\sum_ka_k{n\choose k}=T_n+S_n.
$$
The previous-to-last identity reads $T_n=S_{n+1}-2S_n-1$ hence the last identity reads
$$
S_{n+2}-2S_{n+1}-1=(S_{n+1}-2S_n-1)+S_n,
$$
which indicates that $A=$ $____$ and $B=$ $____$.

Comment: It's nice,Thank you very much